# julia UndefVarError: unshift! not defined

Tags: python, julia

I use julia 1.4, and running the following code:

```
using PyCall
using JLD
using ArgParse
using Pandas
@pyimport networkx as nx
@pyimport scipy.sparse.csgraph as csg
@pyimport numpy as np

unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")
# unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "..")
unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "combinatorial")
@pyimport utils.load_graph as lg
@pyimport utils.distortions as dis
@pyimport graph_util as gu
....
```

when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: unshift! not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /root/hyperbolics/combinatorial/comb.jl:9
 [2] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [3] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:288
 [4] _start() at ./client.jl:484
in expression starting at /root/hyperbolics/combinatorial/comb.jl:9
```

When I searched documents, unshift! is existing function in julia 1.4, so I don't get why this error occurs. I'm new to julia, please help.

Comment: Try to post minimal examples (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, `unshift!([1, 2, 3], 4)` would result in the same error, and does not require any of the 4 external packages you have in your code. The process of creating a small example is also often helpful in finding the problem yourself.

Comment: When you're following old posts and see errors like this, a good thing to try is running them on Julia 0.7. There, you'll get deprecation warnings that notify you how to use the replacement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> unshift! is existing function in julia 1.4

Where did you see this? It was renamed for Julia 1.0 two years ago to [`pushfirst!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pushfirst!):

```
julia> pushfirst!([1, 2, 3], 4)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: If you look up `unshift!`, it is referenced many places like here: https://biojulia.net/BioSequences.jl/v0.8/sequences/bioseq.html#Base.unshift! for example. This SO question will hopefully clarify any future confusion.

Comment: @logankilpatrick Biosequences.jl#v0.8.3 was released Feb 28, 2018 (half year before Julia 1.0) and the current version is 2.0.5 so perhaps this is not a good counter-example?

Comment: AH, you are right, I did not see that at all. Thanks for pointing this out!